# What is the acceptable value for Live Bytes in Intsruments?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management, instruments

I was running my iphone app, optimizing to reduce memory footprint etc. I see that the live byte shows around 3.5 - 4 MB.

I was wondering what is an acceptable value. Put other way, what is the ceiling I should try to stay under.

Related thoughts, at what level do I get memory warnings, like level 1 level 2 memory warnings?

I am guessing this will have a direct correlation to my iphone device. Is there a matrix we can build depending on the device. I am using iphone 3G

thanks a ton
mb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you stay under 20MB you should be fine, but as always the less you use the better ;-).

as far as I know the it isn't documented when the memory warnings are triggered, probably because that it is implementation detail and it can change at any moment.

Anyway you shouldn't focus too much on numbers (you don't know other memory consuming processes (safari caching pages, apps in the background using memory), just be a good ios-citizen, make sure you don't leak memory all over the place and your app will be working like a charm.